# How to find the routers in a LAN

Tags: networking, router, lan, network-discovery

I am connected to a LAN, say 10.1.1.0/24. I discovered that there are several other systems connected to the LAN (say 15 to 20), but Nmap wouldn't tell clearly what they are (OS detection wise). The IP adresses I discovered do not follow a recognizable pattern, i.e. there is no system with address 10.1.1.1 or similar. I know that one of them is a router. How could I figure out, which one it is?

Comment: set one external ip routing via one of them and wait for ping replies.

Comment: Do you definitely know it is a router, rather than a firewall?  If you aren't sure, then a firewall might not show up on a basic nmap scan, you'd need to do an arp scan in nmap.  Do you definitely know the subnet mask is correct?

Answer (score 3):

There is no 100% working method, but try this as a start:

- Many routers also host a DHCP server – broadcast a DHCPDISCOVER (using `dhclient` or `dhcpcd`) and see who replies. Likewise with IPv6 Router Discovery (using `rdisc6` or `rtsol`).
- Try *using* it as a gateway – send it a packet with a foreign IP address as destination, and see if it gets forwarded or if you get an ICMP error or nothing. (You could either add an actual route within the OS itself, using `ip route add` or such, or you could manually craft packets using `scapy` or `nemesis`.)
- Ping `ff02::2` (IPv6 all-routers multicast) and compare MAC addresses of replies with your IPv4 scan results. Not all operating systems respond to multicast pings, but quite a few do.
- Using tcpdump/tshark, watch IGMP packets – some routers periodically send IGMP group queries to verify who is subscribed.
- Try the last address (`.254/24`) as well as the middle two addresses.
- Consider that the network might not have a gateway. It is also technically valid, although *annoying*, for the gateway to be outside of the subnet. (Some VM hosting providers do that...)